# SQLite API changes proximal to Xcode 6.3 release?

Tags: sqlite.swift

After updating to Xcode 6.3/Swift 1.2 I'm getting these errors.  (`.NoCase` can't be found, and `.insert` doesn't accept `(Setter, Setter)`.

Did something change in the SQLite swift API?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) is still young so the API is still a bit in flux as things tighten up. Sorry for the inconvenience!

1. Collating sequence names have been un-camelcased. See: https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/commit/74e80d3eb4b1108b37c2acec3321cf27f5037843

   > Upgrade path: `.Nocase`.
2. Insert's overload returns an `Int64` now. See: https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/commit/5380d5b502bd76ea99fe0ec54785f6bacd1cb8c1

   > Update path: return `Int64?` from `saveNotes`.

Comment: Worked great, but am I missing something obvious to think Swift generated a rather confusing/misleading error message in the case of insert()?

Comment: You're not missing anything. At the moment, a lot of Swift errors unfortunately cascade, obscuring the root problem. You usually have to split logic up into more pieces to find the underlying issue.